# How to justify SVG text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, svg

I'm trying to justify text within `<tspan>` elements using javascript since SVG doesn't support `text-align: justify` yet. I'm sure that I'm pretty close to the right solution but can't seem to get the correct amount of word-spacing between words so that each line is justified to both the left and right.

Here's a [CodePen link](http://codepen.io/coreybruyere/pen/YwweQB?editors=101) to the issue to see it in its entirety. Just click on one of the buttons on the bottom of the page to run the function(scroll down page to see buttons).

But I believe the problem lies somewhere here:

First I'm looping through each `<tspan>` element and pushing it's original length to an array.

```
for (i = 0; i < tspan.length; i++) {
 spanText.push(tspan[i].offsetWidth);
}
```

Then I store the longest value from that array in a variable

```
longestSpan = Math.max.apply(Math, spanText);
```

Then I loop through each `<tspan>` one more time and calculate the needed spacing between each word to justify the text of each line to the largest `<tspan>`'s width

```
for (i = 0; i < tspan.length; i++) {
 var spanLength = longestSpan - tspan[i].offsetWidth;
 var wordCount = tspan[i].innerHTML.split(/\s/).length;
 var wordSpacing = spanLength / (wordCount - 1);
 tspan[i].setAttribute('word-spacing', wordSpacing);
}
```

As you can see in the link above the justified text on each line is slightly off.

Is there a pure SVG solution to this? If not, how do I properly calculate the spacing between each word to get justified text.

Comment: According to http://www.w3.org/1999/07/30/WD-SVG-19990730/text.html#CSSTextPropertiesUsedBySVG you can not use `text-aling: justify`

Comment: Right below that is says: _These options from CSS2 [CSS2] are not supported by SVG. Specifying them will result in a value of left being used._

Answer (score 1):

Just [fixed](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeVPKV) spacing calculation:

```
wordSpacing = spanLength / (wordCount-1) / 2
```

Subtracted 1 to get number of spaces and found that spacing is doubled. Also fixed word count calculation.

Comment: The minus 1 makes sense now, but why divide by 2? I tried with `(wordCount - 1)` and got more desirable results than both the original code and the divide by 2 suggestion. But some of the lines are still slightly off. I know there probably isn't a perfect solution but it seems as if the first and last line are longer than the rest.